# depois de uma linha de php o codigo html nao carrega

Tags: php, html, mysql, banco-de-dados, chat

o problema é que eu quero que pagina carregue ja com as mensagens, se for com javascript ela demora pra carergar eu tentei usar o incluide para ja vim com o arquivo php das mensagens, porem depois que eu fiz isso, o resto do codigo html e php nao estao sendo carregados.

```
<div class="trabalhador">



                <ul id="mensagens">
                    <? include('chat/load-msg.php')// o problema esta aqui, quando eu coloquei essa linha não carregou mais a o resto do codigo abaixo.; ?>
                </ul>
                



            <div class="div1-do-botao-no-meio">

                <form action="chat/send-msg.php" method="post"id="id">

                    <textarea id="text" rows="4" cols="33" type="text" name="msg" maxlength="275" placeholder=""></textarea><br>

                    <input class="btn-entrar" type="submit" value="Enviar">

                    <br><h3>Escolha uma cor!<br>

                    <input class="corcor"type="color" name="cor" value="<? echo $_SESSION['cor'];?>"></input>

                </form>

            </div>

        </div>
```

**load-msg.php:**

```
<?php

include('../conexao.php');


$sql = "SELECT * FROM mensagens ORDER BY id ASC";

$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

        echo "<li class='message'><strong class='username'style='color:".$row["cor"]."'>".$row["username"].":</strong> ".$row["mensagens"]."</li>";

    }

}else {

    echo "Ainda não há mensagens.";

};



$conn->close();
```

**e fica assim:**
[print da origem da pagina do navegador](https://i.stack.imgur.com/44TZc.png)

```
        </div>



        <div class="trabalhador">

            <div>

                <ul id="mensagens">
```

esse é o ultimo código fonte do navegador

Comment: Em vez de duplicar postagens, edite [sua pergunta original](/q/588893/70) conforme as orientações já passadas lá. Para evitar duplicidade de informações, o campo de comentários foi desativado aqui, mas continua disponível no primeiro post que fez sobre esta dúvida.